# Why he wrote movie.haveWatched , movie.title , movie.rating?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This code is wrote by my online teacher colt steel(web development bootcamp teacher) but I can't understand why he wrote movie.haveWatched , movie.title , movie.rating. I think there should be movieDb.haveWatched , movieDb.title , movieDb.rating because haveWatched, title, rating are inside of movieDb.

```js
var movieDb = [ { title:"gujja",
                  rating:5,
                  haveWatched:true, },
                { title:"la",
                  rating:5,
                  haveWatched:false,}];
movieDb.forEach(function(movie){
        var result = "you have ";
       if (movie.havewatched){
          result += "watched ";
}else {
          result += "not seen ";
}
result += `${movie.title} -`
result += `${movie.rating}`
console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

movieDb is an array of objects.

In this function:

```
movieDb.forEach(function(movie){
//code
}
```

the movieDb is being iterated over, and each element in the array is being acted on.

So `movie` is a variable, within that forEach function.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is a higher order function.
`movie` in this case, refers to each element of the array, one at a time as it is passed to the callback function inside `forEach`.

More information about this method here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

In fact, you can name it whatever you want.
This would also be valid code, but might not make very much sense:

`` movieDb.forEach(function(callItAnything){
  var result = "you have ";
  if (callItAnything.havewatched){
    result += "watched ";
  } else {
    result += "not seen ";
  }
  result += `${callItAnything.title} -`
  result += `${callItAnything.rating}`
  console.log(result);
}); ``

Also, it is very useful to learn to pay attention to indenting your code properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Following are the key points to understand the code

- Your data is in the `movieDb` **array** and there are **2 movies** in that.
- Each **movie** is an **object** having properties `haveWatched`, `title` and `rating`.
- `forEach` **function** iterates over array and passes 1 item in an array at one time to the callback function.
- `movieDb.forEach` iterates over the `movieDb` array and gives a **movie object** to the callback function
- Now, the callback function has an object with the said properties which are being access by `dot operator (.)`

Comment: Thanks sir you are right also. you got me the whole thing!

Comment: Glad to help you :)